# Group elements in python-list by type

Tags: python, list

I have a heterogeneous list and I want to group its elements by type.

Let's say, I have:

```
l = [[], 1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', [5, 6]]
```

I want:

```
l = [[[], [5, 6]], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']]
```

Where the order doesn't really matter.

What's a python-ic way to do that?

*I don't want loops inside of loops inside of loops.*

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your "non pythonic" attempts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [[], 1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', [5, 6]]

accumulation = defaultdict(list)
for e in l:
    accumulation[type(e)].append(e)

result = list(accumulation.values())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[[], [5, 6]], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']]
```

As an alternative you could use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
accumulation = {}
for e in l:
    accumulation.setdefault(type(e), []).append(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, using the inbuilt [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) which gives you the option of either a list or a dictionary as your return values:

```
l = [[], 1, 2, 'a', 3, 'b', [5, 6]]

rv = dict()

for thing in l:
    if type(thing) in rv:
        rv[type(thing)].append(thing)
    else:
        rv[type(thing)] = [thing]

print([x for x in rv.values()])
```

**Output:**

```
[[[], [5, 6]], [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']]
```

or:

```
>>> rv
{list: [[], [5, 6]], int: [1, 2, 3], str: ['a', 'b']}
```